# How To Apply Trigger To Image

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm very new to WPF (and quite frankly I don't know why WinForms even exists because in my opinion it's FAR inferior to WPF), so I'm still not quite in the swing of things.

I have a TabControl, and inside each TabHeader is an image. Essentially, I just want the selected TabItem to have an Image with a gaussian blur radius of 2 and all the non-selected TabItems to have an Image with a gaussian blur of 8.

I've been looking through a lot of material on XAML, WPF, triggers, etc. and I'm just overwhelmed with information. Could someone help me out?

Comment: Can you show your tab header template if you have one?

Comment: @dkozl I don't have any templates in my XAML file, but I'm using [MahApps.Metro](http://mahapps.com/) to style everything if that helps.

Comment: `"I don't know why WinForms even exists because in my opinion"` WPF needs `Silverlight` plugin whereas `WinForm` you don't need a plug in. Reach v. Rich

Comment: @Zuzlx Hmmm, I never knew that! I understand now but Silverlight is free so I suppose it's not too bad.

Comment: @Zuzlx I'd like to see a source on that.  To the best of my knowledge WPF has absolutely no dependency on Silverlight whatsoever.

Comment: @Zuzlx Jon B is right --> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921107%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx

Comment: Sorry...right....I was thinking browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that by changing `Effect` on the image depending on `TabItem.IsSelected`. Lets say this is your `Image` in the `Header`

```xml
<Image Source="...">                        
   <Image.Style>
       <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
           <Setter Property="Effect">
               <Setter.Value>
                   <BlurEffect Radius="8"/>
               </Setter.Value>
           </Setter>
           <Style.Triggers>
               <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                   <Setter Property="Effect">
                       <Setter.Value>
                           <BlurEffect Radius="2"/>
                       </Setter.Value>
                   </Setter>
               </DataTrigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
   </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

basically you create `DataTrigger` which binding goes up the visual tree to `TabItem` and trigger on `IsSelected=true`

Comment: You're a freaking genius. Hahaha, WPF is awesome! Thanks :)